# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'beans:bean'

Tags: java, spring, servlets, xsd

> One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":meta, "h
>       ttp://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":constructor-arg, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":property, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":qualifier, "http://www.springframework.or
>       g/schema/beans":lookup-method, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":replaced-method, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.

Tomcat is showing me above error

My spring-servlet.xml is given below. I am using .3.11.RELEASE version of springframework.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="in.project.*" />


    <annotation-driven/>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root entity of the xml application context is `<beans>`, not `<bean>`.
So you might end up with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">
...
</beans:beans>
```

Haven't tested is but should work. Hope that helps.